# Removing values in a range from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, return

I want to remove values in a range from an array. For example, `removeVals([20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70], 2, 4)` should return the array `[20, 30, 70]`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one-liner. If you're unfamiliar with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) this might be a bit confusing but I'll put my solution out there anyway.

```js
var removeVals = (array, start, end) => array.filter((item, index) => index < start || index > end);
console.log(removeVals([20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70], 2, 4)) // [20, 30, 70]
```

JavaScript's built-in [`filter` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) iterates through an array, and passes each item (and the index of said item optionally) into the function that it's provided. If the return value of that function is true, then the item stays in the array, otherwise it is removed. The function that we pass into the `filter` function only returns true if the index of the current item in the array is less than the beginning of the range or more that the end of the range, therefore removing items that are *in* the range.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#splice`, which changes the input array. So you would need to return the modified array.

**DEMO**

```js
const removeVals = (arr, start, end) => arr.splice(start, end-start+1) && arr;

console.log( removeVals([20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70], 2, 4) );
```

Comment: This is a much better answer, I didn't think of using `splice`.

Comment: Glad you found this useful. @dada feel free to accept it as the answer if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

### Method-1

This method removes the subset in the range `Array[startIx, stopIx]` from the source array using the `Array.prototype.splice()`method.

```js
// INPUT  → array[0, array.length - 1]
// OUTPUT → array[0, startIx - 1] U array[stopIx + 1, array.length - 1]
let removeVals = (array, startIx, stopIx) => {
  array.splice(startIx, stopIx - startIx + 1);
  return array;
}

let array= [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
console.log(`Result: ${removeVals(array, 2, 4)}`);
```

### Method-2

1. Create a new array inside the function.
2. Add the values in the range `array[0, startIx - 1]` to the new array.
3. Add values from range `array[stopIx+ 1, array.lenght - 1]` to the new array.

```js
// INPUT  → array[0, array.length - 1]
// OUTPUT → array[0, startIx - 1] U array[stopIx + 1, array.length - 1]
let removeVals = (array, startIx, stopIx) => {
  let resultArray = []
  
  for(let i = 0; i < startIx ; ++i)
    resultArray.push(array[i])
  
  for(let i = stopIx + 1 ; i < array.length ; ++i)
    resultArray.push(array[i])
    
  return resultArray;
}

let array= [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
console.log(`Result: ${removeVals(array, 2, 4)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works like `.filter()` demonstrated in [tybocopperkettle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72932770/2813224), but with `.flatMap()` instead. Using a ternary in `.flatMap()` gives us an advantage of returning almost any value.

```js
idx < a || idx > z ? num : []
```

| JavaScript | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `idx < a` | If index is less than start... |
| `||` | ...OR... |
| `idx > z` | ...if index is greater than end... |
| `? num` | ...return the value... |
| `:[]` | ...otherwise return nothing |

<sup>`[]` returns as nothing since `.flatMap()` applies `.flat()` to whatever it returns.</sup>

```js
const arrayA = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70];
const Aa = 2;
const Az = 4;
const arrayB = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
const Ba = 0;
const Bz = 7;

const remVal = (array, a, z) => array
  .flatMap((num, idx) => 
  idx < a || idx > z ? 
  num : []
);

console.log(remVal(arrayA, Aa, Az));
  
console.log(remVal(arrayB, Ba, Bz));
```